# Add additional method to service in unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, mocking

We are using `.NET Core 3.1`. We want to test whether correct messages are passed as an argument to our email service. Probably the way to go is to mock `Send` method and just save the message to in-memory queue/list. How can we do this without modifying the original interface (`IEmailService`)? We need one additional method in our mocked service which returns all the messages that were passed to its `Send` method, something like `List<Message> GetSentEmails()`.

**TestsBase.cs**

```cs
public class TestsBase
{
    protected readonly IServiceScope _scope;
    protected readonly IPaymentService _paymentService;
    protected readonly IEmailService _emailService;
    
    public TestsBase(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
    {
        _scope = factory.Services.CreateScope();
        _paymentService = _scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IPaymentService>();
        _emailService = _scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IEmailService>() as EmailServiceMock;
    }
}

[CollectionDefinition("MyCollection")]
public class MyCollection : ICollectionFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
{

}
```

**PaymentServiceTest.cs**

```cs
[Collection("MyCollection")]
public class PaymentServiceTest : TestsBase
{
    public PaymentServiceTest(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory) : base(factory)
    {

    }
    
    [Fact]
    public void ConfirmPaymentTest()
    {
        // payment service also sends email
        _paymentService.Process(new Payment()
        {
            Amount = 203.12,
            Email = "test@test.com",
            ...
        });
        
        // we want to check if correct email was passed to email service
        var sentEmails = _emailService.GetSentEmails(); // HOW?
    }
}
```

**CustomWebApplicationFactory.cs**

```cs
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            // mock email service
            services.AddScoped<IEmailService, EmailServiceMock>();
        });
    }
}
```

**EmailService.cs**

```cs
public class EmailService : IEmailService
{
    // implementation
}

public class EmailServiceMock : IEmailService
{
    private readonly List<Message> _sentEmails;

    public EmailServiceMock()
    {
        _sentEmails = new List<Message>();
    }
    
    // mocked implementation of all the methods
    // but we also need access to _sentEmails
    
    public void Send(Message message)
    {
        _sentEmails.Add(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: As you say, you need add a access method/property to `_sentEmails` in `EmailServiceMock`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you use [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4) library for this. You could mock your `IEmailService` and use Moq's `Callback` method to capture what arguments were passed to the `Send` method.

You would just need to tweak the initialization of your services.

```
[Fact]
public void ConfirmPaymentTest()
{
    var sentEmails = new List<Message>();
    var emailService = new Mock<IEmailService>();
    var paymentService = new PaymentService(emailService.Object);
    
    emailService
        .Setup(e => e.Send(It.IsAny<Message>()))
        .Callback<Message>(m => sentEmails.Add(m));   // instead of your GetSentEmails()
    
    paymentService.Process(new Payment()
    {
        Amount = 203.12,
        Email = "test@test.com",
        ...
    });
    
    // you can access your sentEmails list here
}
```

Moq is a really powerful library for testing .NET. There are more features that allow you to mock the return of a method, verify the count of how many times a method was invoked, etc.